# undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Trying to apply a rolify method to my user, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why, because current_user should be a global method accessible in every view right? How can it be nil?

Thanks!

**Controller**

```
def show
        @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:id])
        impressionist(@photo)
        @photos = Photo.latest_photos
        @user = @photo.user
        @pin = Pin.new
        @pin.photo_id = @photo.id
        @category = Category.all
        @commentable = @photo
        @comments = @commentable.comments
        @comment = Comment.new
        @sponsors = @photo.sponsors
        @zone = Zone.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html #show.html.erb
            format.json {render json: @photo}
        end
    end
```

**My view**

```
  <% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
    <%= link_to "Eliminar", user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id) , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'}, class: "delete right" %>
    <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id), :class=> "link", class: "edit quarter_margin_right right" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have a `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller , to authenticate and set the `current_user` ?

Comment: `current_user` is a method accessible in every view, but in your case it returns `nil` and that's why you have an error.

Comment: @MarekLipka I know, just didn't understand why :(

Comment: Great, I'll post an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if there is a `current_user` in your views:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.has_role?(:admin) %>
    <%= link_to "Eliminar", user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id) , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'}, class: "delete right" %>
    <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id), :class=> "link", class: "edit quarter_margin_right right" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This uses boolean short-circuiting - if current_user is nil then  `current_user.has_role? :admin` is never evaluated.

If you are using Devise you can also use the `user_signed_in?` helper method.

### Added.

If you find a yourself doing this often you can create a helper method:

```
# app/helpers/roles_helper.rb
module RolesHelper
  def has_role?(role)
    current_user && current_user.has_role?(role)
  end
end
```

You can then simplefy your view:

```
<% if has_role?(:admin) %>
    <%= link_to "Eliminar", user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id) , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'}, class: "delete right" %>
    <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: pin.id), :class=> "link", class: "edit quarter_margin_right right" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that we are calling `has_role?` on the view context.

Comment: Thought it was an authentication problem, the problem was on checking current_user before using has_role. Thanks!

Comment: Technically you need to put `<% if current_user && current_user.has_role?(:admin) %>`

Answer (score 0):

For Devise to authenticate and set the `current_user`, you can include the following `before_action` in your controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

If you only want to authenticate user for a specific action:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :update]
```

If you want to authenticate the user for all your controllers you can just put it in your `ApplicationController`